# Group element in list by content

Tags: java, list, parsing

I can't group elements in list by content. We have follow list:

```
 67 = "6.1"
 68 = "6.1.1"
 69 = "6.1.2"
 70 = "6.1.3"
 71 = "6.1.4"
 72 = "6.1.5"
 73 = "6.2"
 74 = "6.2.1"
 75 = "6.2.2"
 76 = "6.2.3"
 77 = "6.2.4"
 78 = "6.2.5"
 79 = "6.2.6"
 80 = "6.2.7"
 81 = "6.2.9"
 82 = "6.2.10"
 83 = "6.2.12"
 84 = "6.2.13"
 85 = "6.2.14"
 86 = "6.2.15"
 87 = "6.2.16"
 88 = "6.2.18"
 89 = "6.2.19"
 90 = "6.2.20"
 91 = "6.2.21"
 92 = "6.3"
 93 = "6.3.1"
 94 = "6.3.2"
 95 = "6.3.3"
 96 = "6.3.4"
 97 = "6.4"
 98 = "6.4.2"
 99 = "6.4.3."
```

How can I find all elements such as 6.2 => 6.2.x?

```
private static void filterNumbers(List<String> numbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            final int index = i;
            List<String> result = numbers.stream().filter(n -> n.contains(numbers.get(index))).collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried and tested your code? You are storing your results in a list you are doing nothing with. Does replacing your loop with the following yield the result you are expecting? `List<String> result = numbers.stream().filter(n -> n.startsWith("6.2")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: yes. i use breakpoint by condition :). I think about regexp.

Comment: @RinatMukhaledgaliev As keen as I am about regex, I think this would be overkill for your situation (and regex are not the strong suit of Java). In Java less than 8, you would create a result list, then iterate over your source list and add every item beginning with `"6.2"` (`String.startsWith(String)` is the way to go) to the result list. I have no JDK 8 to test the Stream right now, but it seems a good idea too.

Comment: startsWith("6.2") would also include 6.20, 6.21, etc. You must do startsWith("6.2.") or equals("6.2").

Comment: Awesome @Chop, please post as answer. I mark it as solution of my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using a stream (Java 8)

I have no JDK 8 to test this and I am not used to [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) but I guess you could write your solution this way:

```
// Predicate is "6.2"
private static List<String> filterNumbers(List<String> numbers, String predicate) {
    return numbers.stream().filter(n -> n.equals(predicate) || n.startsWith(predicate + '.')).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

#### Older versions

If you want to be backward compatible or are simply not at ease with the `Stream`, you could still go old-school using [`String.startsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) (and get an easily readable for the average developer):

```
private static List<String> filterNumbers(List<String> numbers, String predicate) {
    List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String n : numbers) {
        if (n.equals(predicate) || n.startsWith(predicate + '.')) {
            filtered.add(number);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

#### Remark about the predicate

As [John Kuhns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2799662/john-kuhns) noticed, `nb.startsWith("6.2")` will return `"6.2"`, `"6.2.1"`, but also `"6.20"`.

To avoid this, you should adapt your test to `nb.equals("6.2") || nb.startsWith("6.2.")`.

#### A thought about regex

Regex was thought of a potential solution.

I love them, they are powerful, but if you can avoid them, do it! They are not the most efficient feature of Java (though my knowledge of this may be getting old). Plus, I know many developers who are just confused when they run into one.